# How I resolve the absolute path of a relative or absolute file name input parameter in a powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a script that produces an output file which I want the user to specify the name of. The name can be input as relative or absolute path. When relative it's relative the current directory

Given this pseudo code...:

```
function global:FileProduce() {
   Param([Parameter] [String] $dest)
   $absoluteDest=(DoSomething $dest)
}
```

..when run from `c:\temp` I want the following input to produce the following output (`$absoluteDest`):

Case 1:

```
Input:
$dest=foo.txt
Output:
c:\temp\foo.txt
```

Case 2:

```
Input:
$dest=sub\bar.txt
Output:
c:\temp\sub\bar.txt
```

Case 3:

```
Input:
$dest=c:\foo.txt
Output:
c:\foo.txt
```

- I've tried `Resolve-Path` but it fails if the file doesn't already exist.
- `$PSScriptRoot` doesn't help because I want the path to be relative to the current folder, not the folder of the script
- `Get-Location` is fine for resolving the current directory but I don't know if the input path is relative or absolute, so `(Get-Location + $dest)`  will fail for absolute paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET's [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netcore-3.1) will achieve exactly that:

```bsh
[System.IO.Path]::Combine($pwd, $dest)
```

(`$pwd` is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#pwd) containing the full path of the current directory)